# Partial results in a MVC3 grid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, websocket

I query a few third party subsystems. Some take 20 seconds to return, another 5 seconds to return. I dont want the user hang on the waitscreen for 20 seconds and return partial results. (Caching results for better speed is not possible)

Is there a framework or even better a jquery extension which can help me doing this? I am looking for something which supports web sockets, but aswell a polling approach for older clients.

What is the best pattern to do this? I thaught about using Redis as Polling Server. Any better ideas?

Comment: Isn't AJAX enough or you need to support some progress, etc...? Web sockets is for the server pushing content to the client, not the client pulling contents from the server which is AJAX.

Comment: lets say sub system one returns after 5 seconds 100 items, i want to show them as soon i received them. after 20 seconds i want to add another 300 items to the result grid.

Comment: @Snoopy, could you in this case load the first 100 items and render the view immediately (after 5 seconds) and then trigger an AJAX request that will fetch the other items asynchronously from the server and append them to the grid once the request completes (after 20 seconds)?

Comment: Yes. But i dont know how long the second request takes. So i might poll several times, which would be okay. I thaught there might be some framework to simplify things as this looks like a reusable problem to me.

Comment: Well...if you don't mind being somewhat selfish, you could just tie up one of the threads normally used for Ajax requests for 20 seconds (or however long it takes) and have the server respond to the request when it gets data.  Basically the same thing as a page taking a long time to load, but in the background.  It might screw over other Ajax apps that may be running at the same time but you avoid polling =).

Comment: ROMANARMY: i first thaught about this dirty approach too, but i am afraid this approach will not scale very well :-) I hope that someone comes with something new up so that i maybe learn something :)

Comment: Not scale well in what way?  I can't imagine you needing to make enough of these requests from the browser to tie up all (or many) of the threads (not sure if that's the right term).  And on the server doesn't sound like you can get around long requests.

Comment: R0MANARMY: i mean with not scaleing well i dont want to use a sticky session which means my browser is not tied to a specific server.

Comment: Why would you need to use a sticky session for this?  Server takes time to respond to a really long request and you're done, next request can be handled by a different server.

Comment: May I ask why these requests take so long? What kind of services are you querying?

Comment: Eli: screenscraping of several webpages and terminal screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you getting JSON feeds, have you looked into jQuery's extend method?
Example:

2 Ajax requests, difference in time they respond, both calls the same callback function;

```
$(function(){
    $.listitems = {};       
    var handleItems = function(data, status){
        if(data){ // check that you have what you need
            $.extend($.listitems, data[0]); // Merge the old and new data
            refreshItems();
        }       
    };
    var refreshItems = function(){
        var markup = [];
        for(var a in $.listitems){
            markup.push('<li>' + $.listitems[a].name + '</li>')
        };
        $('#container').html(markup.join());
    }   
    $.ajax({ url: 'feed1.json', dataType: 'json', success: handleItems});
    $.ajax({ url: 'feed2.json', dataType: 'json', success: handleItems});
});
```

If you prefer using Arrays instead of Objects, you could look into [Underscore js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)
and it's _.flatten method.

Answer (score 3):

you could try to use [Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) with Jquery

*

> Rx is a superset of the standard LINQ
>   sequence operators that exposes
>   asynchronous and event-based
>   computations as push-based, observable
>   collections via the new .NET 4.0
>   interfaces IObservable and
>   IObserver. These are the
>   mathematical dual of the familiar
>   IEnumerable and IEnumerator
>   interfaces for pull-based, enumerable
>   collections in the .NET Framework.

- *

> We’re proud to announce the
>   availability of Reactive Extensions
>   for Javascript. This port brings the
>   power of Reactive programming to
>   JavaScript. It allows you to use the
>   Rx combinators in JavaScript, and it
>   does this in a download size of less
>   than 7Kb (GZipped). RxJS provides
>   easy-to-use conversions from existing
>   DOM, XmlHttpRequest, and jQuery events
>   to Rx push-collections, allowing users
>   to seamlessly plug Rx into their
>   existing JavaScript-based web sites.

*

Comment: A bit abstract answer, could you get a bit more concrete?